# Connecting Arduino Yun to wifi with 802.1X authentication

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, linux

Is it possible to connect the Yun to wifi using 802.1X authentication?  802.1X is WPA2-Enterprise that uses a username and password (per user) instead of one password (for every user).  I don't see a way to do it from the Yun web interface, but is there a way to do it from the linino terminal?

As far as I know, the Atheros AR9331 chip should be capable of this, but I don't see a way to do it with the software included on linino, there must be a way to install something for this?

Comment: The question would ultimately be if this is requires any hardware changes, and if not if it is implemented in code which is open source and modifiable, or some propriety binary-blob chipset firmware or driver.